# Some times totals not updating after ajax remove and update quantity

Tags: magento-1.14.3.3

In basket page I'm trying to update product quantity totals not getting update in ajax request. If I refresh page totals showing correct. This issue i'm facing only sometimes

Comment: Check your ajax request in console for more information about ajax, check if any error showing or not ?

Comment: No errors in console